# How can I test namespaces in app engine on localhost (python)?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, namespaces

I'm starting to develop a multitenant app in Google App Engine with python and I could use some help to extract the user's subdomain for testing the namespaces during development.

From the documentation and books I found out how to set the namespace to a fixed string (say 'abc') by creating appengine_config.py and defining its content as follows:

```
from google.appengine.api import namespace_manager

def namespace_manager_default_namespace_for_request():
    return 'abc'    # Used to test
```

I can store new items in the Datastore under namespace 'abc' as all Datastore operations will now use this namespace in the running session. If I then change this to say 'def' and run the app again data is separate from before. So far so good.

However, I need to test setting the namespace automatically during development (= localhost) so that we can be truly shure we're keeping clients stuff separate from each other e.g. logging in to localhost:8080 at the same time from Chrome and Mozilla with users from different subdomains to make sure there are no data leaks.

Say I log in with user@abc.example.com, I need to extract the 'abc' without having to parse the user's email myself.

I changed appengine_config.py to the following:

```
from google.appengine.api import namespace_manager

def namespace_manager_default_namespace_for_request(): 
    return namespace_manager.google_apps_namespace()
```

However, it always returns None as namespace in localhost.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong or which function I can use to extract the users subdomain inside appengine_config.py?

Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: ,  See https://github.com/googlearchive/appengine-guestbook-namespaces-python/blob/master/appengine_config.py has examples of different ways of getting a namespace.  Remember it is called if no namespace has been defined when a request is made.

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks for the tip. I used the cookies approach to set the namespace.